# Socket.io rooms/namespaces - wildcards possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I've the following hierarchy: `Store -> Manager -> Assistant`

A `Manager` can access everything sent by `Assistant`, the `Assistant` can only access what the `Manager` specifically provides.

As far as I understood I could create [namespaces or rooms](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/), e.g. named  `manager_assistant1`, `manager_assistant2`, etc.

Result: `Assistant` (id: 1) listens to `manager_assistant1`. That's fine. But what about the `Manager`? Is it possible to listen to `manager_*`?

My current client just listens to the stream and outputs data which was sent to or from it. That's bad.

**Server**

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('myEvent', function(data) {

        // do something with the data
        // ...

        // return the modified data
        io.emit('myEvent', data);
    });
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

**Client**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:3000/');
socket.emit('myEvent', {
    from: 'assistant1',
    to: 'manager',
    key: 'value'
});

socket.on('myEvent', function(data) {
    var user = 'assistant1'; // or 'manager', 'assistant2', ...
    if (data.from == user || data.to == user) { 
        console.log(data.key); 
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create some logic in more high level, using channels and try to send your bussiness data in json eg.

Try to look in package like that 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs-rooms